# is there any way to run a docker image on host from other docker image?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, ubuntu, docker-swarm

First i'm beginner, bad in explaining thing but i real need help.

i'm trying to create a cluster for MapReduce(my own MapReduce platform)using docker,
 so here is how:

1- Run Ubuntu container (Represent the Resource manager: to  controller the number of node to be created).[this container contain listener code every time need to create  an new node,mapperNode,reduceNode,...].

2- Resource manager node or Ubuntu image  should be able to create a new ubuntu container on host.

Note there is no need to understand MapRedce things 

 **the question is how can i run other Ubuntu container on host From Ubuntu container?**

Comment: Which OS is the host running? Also Ubuntu?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes

Comment: If you can run the cluster from this image on another host, you should be able to do the same on the same host as well as long as all pre-requisites for the other host and met with the same host (say network connectivity, ssh access, etc.) Think of the your first container and the host as de-coupled systems.

Whether it is recommended or not is different.
Have you tried it? Did you run into any issues? Can you post what you've tried and where specifically you're running into issues and need help?

Comment: Remember that, if you can run any `docker` command at all, you can trivially root the host.  Take security concerns very seriously if you attempt this.

Comment: @DavidMaze how i can do this (trivially root the host)?

Comment: `docker run -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/shadow` and disable root’s password, for a start.